# Scraping web data from JSON with python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I would like to scrape timetable data from [this API](https://booking.snav.it/api/v1/rates/1040/2019-02-25/1042/2019-02-25?lang=1). The data returned is in JSON format. I'm using python.

I've tried the following code:

```
snav_timetable_url = "https://booking.snav.it/api/v1/rates/1040/2019-02-25/1042/2019-02-25?lang=1"
fh = urllib.request.urlopen(snav_timetable_url)
snav_timetable = fh.read().decode('utf-8')
fh.close()
snav_timetable_data = json.loads(snav_timetable[len(snav_timetable)-2])
snav_timetable_data_cleaned = []
for departure in snav_timetable_data ['data']['ratesOutward']:
    snav_timetable_data_cleaned.append({
       'COMPANY': 'Snav',
       'CODICE CORSA': departure['coditinera'],
       'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': departure['strDatapart'],
       'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': departure['strDatarri']
    })
```

but get error

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just as a note, you're not "scraping" anything, this is how a json api is supposed to be used.

Comment: Why are you indexing the JSON string? `snav_timetable[len(snav_timetable)-2]` is not a valid JSON document, that's a single character from the document. Just decode *the whole string*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled strDataarri for one.

In addition the requests library might make this a lot cleaner looking.

```
import requests
snav_timetable_url = "https://booking.snav.it/api/v1/rates/1040/2019-02-25/1042/2019-02-25?lang=1"
r = requests.get(snav_timetable_url).json()

snav_timetable_data_cleaned = []
for departure in r['data']['ratesOutward']:
    snav_timetable_data_cleaned.append({
       'COMPANY': 'Snav',
       'CODICE CORSA': departure['coditinera'],
       'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': departure['strDatapart'],
       'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': departure['strDataarri']
    })
```

Output:

```
[{'COMPANY': 'Snav',
  'CODICE CORSA': 'NABECASA',
  'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': '2019-02-25 08:25',
  'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': '2019-02-25 09:20'},
 {'COMPANY': 'Snav',
  'CODICE CORSA': 'NABECASA',
  'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': '2019-02-25 12:30',
  'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': '2019-02-25 13:25'},
 {'COMPANY': 'Snav',
  'CODICE CORSA': 'NABECASA',
  'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': '2019-02-25 16:20',
  'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': '2019-02-25 17:15'},
 {'COMPANY': 'Snav',
  'CODICE CORSA': 'NABECASA',
  'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': '2019-02-25 19:00',
  'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': '2019-02-25 19:55'},
 {'COMPANY': 'Snav',
  'CODICE CORSA': 'NABECASA',
  'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': '2019-02-26 08:25',
  'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': '2019-02-26 09:20'},
 {'COMPANY': 'Snav',
  'CODICE CORSA': 'NABECASA',
  'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': '2019-02-26 12:30',
  'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': '2019-02-26 13:25'},
 {'COMPANY': 'Snav',
  'CODICE CORSA': 'NABECASA',
  'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': '2019-02-26 16:20',
  'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': '2019-02-26 17:15'},
 {'COMPANY': 'Snav',
  'CODICE CORSA': 'NABECASA',
  'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': '2019-02-26 19:00',
  'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': '2019-02-26 19:55'},
 {'COMPANY': 'Snav',
  'CODICE CORSA': 'NABECASA',
  'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': '2019-02-27 08:25',
  'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': '2019-02-27 09:20'},
 {'COMPANY': 'Snav',
  'CODICE CORSA': 'NABECASA',
  'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': '2019-02-27 12:30',
  'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': '2019-02-27 13:25'},
 {'COMPANY': 'Snav',
  'CODICE CORSA': 'NABECASA',
  'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': '2019-02-27 16:20',
  'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': '2019-02-27 17:15'},
 {'COMPANY': 'Snav',
  'CODICE CORSA': 'NABECASA',
  'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': '2019-02-27 19:00',
  'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': '2019-02-27 19:55'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `requests` library if you are using Python 3.x. Here is how you can get json response.

```
import requests

snav_timetable_url = "https://booking.snav.it/api/v1/rates/1040/2019-02-25/1042/2019-02-25?lang=1"
fh = requests.get(snav_timetable_url)
json_data = fh.json()
```

This way you won't have any errors and can proceed with your parsing.

```
for departure in json_data ['data']['ratesOutward']:
   snav_timetable_data_cleaned.append({
      'COMPANY': 'Snav',
      'CODICE CORSA': departure['coditinera'],
      'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': departure['strDatapart'],
      'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': departure['strDataarri']
   })
```

Comment: requests has a built in json parser, and your code will still lead to an error.

Comment: I ran my code before posting and it works without any errors. Can you tell me what error you got?

Comment: `requests` is the better library if you are using Python 2.x too. Not that you should be using Python 2.x for new projects any longer.

Comment: i thought you had missed the dataarri misspelling from the original comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in trying to decode a single character from the response:

```
>>> snav_timetable[len(snav_timetable)-2]
'}'
```

A single character is no a JSON document, so rightfully, parsing fails. You want to decode *the whole response*:

```
snav_timetable_data = json.loads(snav_timetable)
```

You may want to switch to using the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) instead here, it makes [loading JSON responses](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) from an API trivial:

```
import requests

snav_timetable_data = requests.get(snav_timetable_url).json()

snav_timetable_data_cleaned = []
for departure in snav_timetable_data['data']['ratesOutward']:
    snav_timetable_data_cleaned.append({
       'COMPANY': 'Snav',
       'CODICE CORSA': departure['coditinera'],
       'DEPARTURE DATE TIME': departure['strDatapart'],
       'ARRIVAL DATE TIME': departure['strDataarri']
    })
```

Note that I had to correct a typo in the arrival date time reference; it's `strDataarri`, not `strDatarri`.